# Recursive hierarchical Oracle SQL query

Tags: oracle, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have a source table like below:

```
Emp_ID| Name| Manager_ID
001|abc|005
005|cde|010
010|xyz|050
050 | bcg| 100
100|sta|NULL
```

My requirement is to populate the target table like below:

```
Emp_ID| Name| Manager_1| Manager_2| Manager_3| Manager_4
005|cde|xyz|bcg|sta|NULL
050|bcg|sta| NULL|NULL|NULL
100|sta|NULL|NULL|NULL
001|abc|cde|xyz|bcg|sta
```

I am able to use recursive select through Connect by clause and populate the value for Manager_1 but not able to get through the logic to populate Manager_2, Manager_3 , Manager_4 values as different column values in a single row depending on how many level of hierarchy is present for a certain employee.
Please help.

Comment: The requirement is nonsensical. Unless you know "through external means" (without looking at the data), you won't even know how far (how many columns) the output needs to extend, and without knowing the number of columns ahead of time, it's impossible to write a SQL query. You would need dynamic SQL, which is not recommended and is often a sign of poor design. (The output to this query is clearly poorly designed.) Is this a work assignment or something they teach in class?

Comment: Use the pivot expression.

Comment: What is your current query, and what output does it produce?

Comment: @mathguy: Its kind of work assignment.. which I have tried using 'with select' clause and path options available in Oracle SQL

Comment: @access_granted: can you please elaborate a little more on 'Pivot' option. It will be helpful.

Comment: @suk15 - Do you have a maximum number of levels of managers and managers' managers etc. - so do you know before looking at the data the max. number of columns you will need? If you do that can be done with PIVOT, but if you don't, it can't be done in standard SQL.

Comment: @mathguy: Right now , I do not have a specific number for levels. But for suppose its upto level 10 , we cannot keep on using self join . Can you help with pivot function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following query will help you. But to split the string to individual manager id, you need to know the max no of level of managers.

```
WITH data_set AS
     (SELECT '001' emp_id, 'aaa' emp_name, '005' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '005' emp_id, 'bbb' emp_name, '010' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '010' emp_id, 'ccc' emp_name, '050' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '020' emp_id, 'ddd' emp_name, '050' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '050' emp_id, 'eee' emp_name, '100' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '100' emp_id, 'fff' emp_name, '200' mgr_id
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT '200' emp_id, 'ggg' emp_name, NULL mgr_id
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT     emp_id, emp_name, mgr_id,
           LTRIM (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (emp_id, '-'), '-') chain
      FROM data_set
START WITH mgr_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY mgr_id = PRIOR emp_id
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY emp_id;
```

Comment: Can u post the final query as I am curious about how you finally handled it. Also please mark the answer acceptable if it solved your query @suk15

Answer (score 0):

If your hierarchy only extends to 4 levels deep, the following query may be used:

```
select t1.Emp_ID, 
       t1.Name, 
       t2.Name as Manager_1, 
       t3.Name as Manager_2, 
       t4.Name as Manager_3,
       t5.Name as Manager_4
from tmp t1
left join tmp t2 on t2.Emp_ID = t1.Manager_ID
left join tmp t3 on t3.Emp_ID = t2.Manager_ID
left join tmp t4 on t4.Emp_ID = t3.Manager_ID
left join tmp t5 on t5.Emp_ID = t4.Manager_ID;
```

Comment: It will not be always 4 level deep.. it is dynamic.. it can be 10 also or more than that..

Answer (score 0):

Pivot option:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT emp_id, name, manager_id
  FROM employees
)
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(manager_id)
  FOR manager_id IN ('005', '100', '050')
)
ORDER BY emp_id;
```

Comment: Thank you all for help. @Debabrata answer helped me to think of the final solution